# Beautiful Soup Error: Trying to retrieve data from web page returns empty array

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download a list of voting intention opinion polls from [this web page](https://www.marktest.com/wap/a/p/id~112.aspx#t) using **beautiful soup**. However, the code I wrote returns an empty array or nothing. The code I used is below:

The page code is like this:

```
<div class="ST-c2-dv1 ST-ch ST-PS" style="width:33px"></div>
    <div class="ST-c2-dv2">41.8</div>
```

That's what I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get(quote_page) # take the page link
page = request.content  # extract page content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

# extract all the divs
for each_div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'ST-c2-dv2'}):
    print each_div
```

At this point, it prints nothing.
I've tried also this:

```
tutti_a = soup.find_all("html_element", class_="ST-c2-dv2")
```

and also:

```
tutti_a = soup.find_all("div", class_="ST-c2-dv2")
```

But I get an empty array [] or nothing at all

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following url

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://www.marktest.com/wap/a/sf/v~[73D5799E1B0E]/name~Dossier_5fSondagensLegislativas_5f2011.HighCharts.Sondagens.xml.aspx')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

results = []
for record in soup.select('p'):
    results.append([item.text for item in record.select('b')])
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```

Columns 5,6,7,8,9,10 correspond with PS, PSD,CDS,CDU,Bloco,Outros/Brancos/Nulos

You can drop unwanted columns, add appropriate headers etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I was trying to solve the same problem together with @Attilio. Once I run this piece of code, I get the following error: `FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`. I tried to `pip install lxml`, but the problem still remains. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: Change the parser to 'html.parser' instead of lxml. Let me know if that works. Otherwise there is also 'html5lib'